# Print same index position out of 2 ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, indexing

Given two `ArrayLists`, one containing Strings whereas the other contains Integers.

The next step would be to grab the first position of each `ArrayList` and print them out side by side next to each other.
Then 2, 3, 4 , 5, You name it.

1st List: public List getDoubleHistory(){...}

2nd  : `List<StringBuilder> timeAtThatMoment = new ArrayList<>();`

I guess that we start with a for loop in which i is the index.

Comment: Write some code and come back with a specific question, if you get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we have to assume that the lists are the same size, or else we cannot continue to do as you asked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < getDoubleHistory().size(); i++){
    System.out.println(getDoubleHistory.get(i));
    System.out.println(timeAtThatMoment.get(i));
}
```

If the lists are not the same size you will have to add some if statements to make sure you dont get index out of bounds exceptions.

You can read more on this here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html